# Not able to progressively change the left value of a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple game using JS. In that I have to move the character left when we click on the `A` button in the keyboard. I got the `Keycode` and I am able to change the left property also, but only once. I saw many similar questions, but none of those answers helped.

Here's my code:-

HTML FILE:

```
 <!-- The div that I wanna move -->
    <div class="char-div">
        <img src="game imgs/char-1.png" alt="" id="char-img">
    </div>
```

CSS FILE:

```
.char-div{
/* styling of that div */
position: absolute;
/* top: 0; */
left: 350px;
bottom: 0;
}
```

JS FILE:

```
let char_div = document.getElementsByClassName('char-div')[0];
var char_div_left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(char_div, null).getPropertyValue('left'));
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 65){
        char_div.style.left = char_div_left - 20 + "px";
        console.log(char_div_left)
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 68){
        char_div.style.left = char_div_left + 120 +"px";
        console.log(char_div_left)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate `left` style of `char_div` in each key down event

```js
let char_div = document.getElementsByClassName('char-div')[0];

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  var char_div_left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(char_div, null).getPropertyValue('left'));

            if (e.keyCode == 65) {
                char_div.style.left = char_div_left - 20 + "px";
               // console.log(char_div_left)
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 68) {
                char_div.style.left = char_div_left + 120 + "px";
               // console.log(char_div_left)
            }
        }
```

```css
.char-div {
            /* styling of that div */
            position: absolute;
            /* top: 0; */
            left: 350px;
            bottom: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="char-div">
        <img src="game imgs/char-1.png" alt="this is img" id="char-img">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get these     `<div class="char-div"> <img src="game imgs/char-1.png" alt="" id="char-img"> </div>` inside the `onkeydown` function

```js
let char_div = document.getElementsByClassName('char-div')[0];
var char_div_left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(char_div, null).getPropertyValue('left'));
```

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {

  let char_div = document.getElementsByClassName('char-div')[0];
  var char_div_left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(char_div, null).getPropertyValue('left'));
  if (e.keyCode === 65) {
    char_div.style.left = char_div_left - 5 + "px";

  }
  if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    char_div.style.left = char_div_left + 5 + "px";

  }
}
```

```css
.char-div {
  /* styling of that div */
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 0; */
  left: 350px;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `char_div_left` doesn't update it's value on click, so it holds the initial value for all of the clicks.

I advise, however, against reading the value from computed styles altogether, just create a state variable:

```js
let char_div = document.getElementsByClassName('char-div')[0];
let how_much_left = 350;
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 65){
        how_much_left -= 20;
        char_div.style.left = how_much_left + "px";
        console.log(how_much_left)
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 68){
        how_much_left += 120;
        char_div.style.left = how_much_left + "px";
        console.log(how_much_left)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is more precise solution, this will only listen to the specific events.

```
let char_div = document.getElementsByClassName('char-div')[0];
let char_div_left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(char_div, null).getPropertyValue('left'));

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 68) {
        char_div_left = ( char_div_left + ( e.keyCode == 65 ? -20 : 120 ) );
        char_div.style.left = char_div_left + "px";
    }
}
```